# Displaying Data from different indices of variable inside the Controller, on different ngRoute pages.

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-routing

I wasn't able to word the title in the best way, what I am trying to do is display data that I have stored in different indices of a variable ($scope.data) on different pages using ng-Route.

I'm trying to do this using a classified list as an example so on here ( http://plnkr.co/edit/I3EEqC0aN79UUf10f7az ) I've set up some code to mimic a classifieds list, sorry about the no styling. I can get the first page of listings to display on the page but when I change over to another page using the buttons I've created I get a blank page.

If someone could explain to me what I am doing wrong and where, as well as show me how to fix it I would really appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Plnkr Code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>L</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="LApp">



        <div class="main">
            <div class="container">
                <div ng-view></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Modules -->
        <script src="app.js"></script>

        <!-- Controllers -->
        <script src="HomeController.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>

var app = angular.module("LApp", ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/L/:pageId", {
            controller: "HomeController",
            templateUrl: 'home.html'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: "/L/0"
        });
});

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="page_select">
            <a href="#/L/{{ prevPageIndex }}"><button type="button" class="prev"><img src="#"></button></a>
            <p>{{ currentPageIndex }}</p>
            <a href="#/L/{{ nextPageIndex }}"><button type="button" class="next"><img src="#"></button></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" ng-repeat="lst in listings[currentPageIndex].lsts">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="{{lst.thumbnail}}">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <h4 class="title">{{ lsts.title }}</h4>
            <p class="description">{{ lst.description }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <p class="author">{{ lst.author }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h5 class='rating'>{{ lst.rating }}</h5>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

I didn't include the Controller since the variable holding all the info is very large and it would take up a lot of room.

Comment: At least in your plunker, it's not working because your `$scope.listings` only contacts 1 object. That object is invalid javascript because it contains duplicate keys. This is how your `$scope.listings` looks like in a nutshell `[{page: 1, lsts: [...], page: 2, lsts: [...], etc}]`

Comment: @user2718281 what if I made my $scope.listings to look like so 

[ { {...}, {...}, {...} }, 
  { {...}, {...}, {...} },  
  { {...}, {...}, {...} }]

and I was to iterate through the list of lists?